# Why does "less" sometimes forget its history

Tags: command-history, less

I set and exported `$LESSHISTFILE` and `$LESSHISTSIZE` but if I perform a search in one `less` session, close, reopen it and try to repeat my last search I get "No previous regular expression  (press RETURN)".

It works as expected in Ubuntu 14.04 but not in Fedora release 7. Any suggestion?

It's writing to `$LESSHISTSIZE`. I get the same text written to the history file on both Ubuntu and Fedora. Below I started with an empty history file and then executed `cal | less`. I searched for "xxx" while in `less`. But when I exit and rerun the `less` command it gives me the error message if try to repeat the search with just the `/` command.

```
$ cal | less
$ ls -l  $LESSHISTFILE
-rw------- 1 cs cs 40 Aug  4 14:23 .lesshist
$ cat  $LESSHISTFILE
.less-history-file:
.search
"xxx
.shell
$
```

Maybe it's because the version on Fedora is so old.

```
$ less --version
less 394
Copyright (C) 1984-2005 Mark Nudelman
```

Comment: Where are you exporting these variables, and do they show inside `env` output? If so, what happens when you run `touch $LESSHISTFILE`?

Comment: Thanks. I verified that it does write to the history file. That surprised me. I added an example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 has less 458, and Fedora 7 has less 394.  The `NEWS` file between those versions is the place to look:

> ```
>             Major changes between "less" versions 394 and 406
>
>     * Allow decimal point in number for % (percent) command.
>
>     * Allow decimal point in number for -j option (fraction of screen height).
>
>     * Make n command fetch previous pattern from history file on first search.
> ```

For that, you have to look at the sources (I'm looking at the file from less 451), because the [online history](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/) doesn't go back that far.  You can get older versions from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/less/

Since answering this in 2016, the RCS for less was exported to git [here](https://github.com/gwsw/less), apparently in [mid-2017](https://github.com/gwsw/less/commit/0e360d3fc39e9027ba6a925318c698c0b8c7d458#diff-18af9f096c190ecee96547eb7f1f3bc1), and one can point more accurately to the change ([early 2007](https://github.com/gwsw/less/commit/953ddfa2b287f2c2d37d25de9d021be5601ab870#diff-cb1827d258a66a63915357ce2ee97af7)).  Exactly *when* the switch was done is unclear, since the repository commits are [*unverified*](https://help.github.com/en/articles/managing-commit-signature-verification).